# Can't solve hitbox issues in mobile game made in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am developing a game where objects fall from the top of the screen, and you try to and tap on them before they reach the bottom of the screen. The code works fine when I played the game in the editor (with the touch controls swapped to mouse controls), except when I run the game on a phone, the game only seems to register a successful hit if you tap slightly in front of the object in the direction that it is traveling, and does not register a hit if you tap towards the back end or center of the object. I have built and ran the game over 10 times now, each time trying to fix this issue but nothing seems to help. My theory at the moment is that my code for the touch controls have too much going on and/ or have redundancies and by the time it checks whether or not an object is at the position of the touch, the object has moved to a different location. Any thoughts on why the hit boxes are off, and is there a better way to do hit detection with touch screen?

```
   void FixedUpdate()
     {
         if (IsTouch())
         {
             CheckTouch(GetTouchPosition());
         }
     }


    // Returns true if the screen is touched
         public static bool IsTouch()
         {
             if (Input.touchCount > 0)
             {
                 if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
             }
             return false;
         }


     // Gets the position the touch
         private Vector2 GetTouchPosition()
         {
             Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
             Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

             if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
             {
                 touchPos = touch.position;
             }

             return touchPos;
         }

     // Checks the position of the touch and destroys the ball if the 
        ball is touched
         private void CheckTouch(Vector2 touchPos)
         {
             RaycastHit2D hit = 
             Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(
             (Input.GetTouch(0).position)), Vector2.zero);

             if (hit.collider != null)
              {
                    destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
              }
     }
```

Comment: Is the camera orthographic or perspective?

Comment: I remember we use to Get Input in Update instead of FixedUpdate. Hope this solves the issue.